# bgfx shared library "undefined symbol: XLockDisplay" from .NET Core on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, pinvoke, bgfx

I'm trying to write a simple [bgfx](https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx) application in C# with .NET Core. It works fine on Windows, but it fails **at runtime** on Linux with the following error:

```
/usr/bin/dotnet: symbol lookup error: /home/user/Documents/Projects/GameEngine/GameEngine/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/libbgfx-shared-libDebug.so: undefined symbol: XLockDisplay
```

I'm very ignorant about C++ (especially on Linux) and I already tried all I could think about. I'm looking for hints to fix this problem. **Thank you very much** for your help.

#### Reference Code

[This](https://gitlab.com/bruce965/game-engine/blob/f4c93eb91e40c704790b1e4428f3687d21b3831d/GameEngine.Native/Internal/GameWindowX11.cs#L33) is the constructor of the class I use to create a new X11 window. It works and the window is opened correctly.

```
public GameWindow()
{
    // (snip)

    XInitThreads();

    dpy = XOpenDisplay(IntPtr.Zero);
    if (dpy == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new ApplicationException("XOpenDisplay failed");

    var s = XDefaultScreen(dpy);
    win = XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, XRootWindow(dpy, s), 10, 10, Width, Height, 1, XBlackPixel(dpy, s), XWhitePixel(dpy, s));
    XSelectInput(dpy, win, XEventMask.ExposureMask | XEventMask.KeyPressMask);
    XMapWindow(dpy, win);

    // (snip)

    WM_DELETE_WINDOW = XInternAtom(dpy, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", false);
    XSetWMProtocols(dpy, win, new[] { WM_DELETE_WINDOW }, 1);
}
```

[This](https://gitlab.com/bruce965/game-engine/blob/f4c93eb91e40c704790b1e4428f3687d21b3831d/GameEngine/Program.cs#L89) is where I create the window and assign it to bgfx.

```
using (var window = new GameWindow())
{
    Bgfx.SetWindowHandle(window.Handle);

    var inited = Bgfx.Init();  // <- this line causes the crash

    // (snip)
}
```

[This](https://github.com/MikePopoloski/SharpBgfx/blob/4fba84e527b43a7d6f240b3df5c6be3504e7e86d/SharpBgfx/Bgfx.cs#L218) is the `Bgfx.Init()` function.

```
public static bool Init (InitSettings settings = null) {
    InitSettings.Native native;
    NativeMethods.bgfx_init_ctor(&native);

    // (snip)

    return NativeMethods.bgfx_init(&native);  // <- this line causes the crash
}
```

#### Things I noticed

- The included C++ examples run fine, I'm only encountering this problem from C# (though the library is statically linked in the C++ examples; I'm linking dynamically with PInvoke from C#).
- I identified the crash to be triggered from [glcontext_glx.cpp:66](https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx/blob/97fe8e48a162b3a2197497d829a41c0739ffd593/src/glcontext_glx.cpp#L66). All the code before this line does indeed run (I checked the tracelogs and they are actually printed until the crash, and I do successfully interact from C# with the library in other ways before that function call is made).
- Oddly, the *libbgfx-shared-libDebug.so* (3.6MB) weighs less than the *libbgfx-shared-libRelease.so* (5.4MB). The opposite is true for the [Windows build by Michael Popoloski](https://github.com/MikePopoloski/SharpBgfx/tree/4fba84e527b43a7d6f240b3df5c6be3504e7e86d/external/bgfx) (*bgfx.dll* 728KB and *bgfx_debug.dll* 3.5MB).
- I do `XCreateSimpleWindow()` from C# before initializing bgfx, and the window does appear, therefore the X11 library is actually linked correctly.

#### Things I tried

- Compiling *libbgfx-shared-libDebug.so* from [Michael Popoloski's bgfx fork](https://github.com/MikePopoloski/bgfx) (the author of the PInvoke library I'm using from C#) instead of from the original repository - no change
- Using the release library instead of the debug library - no change
- Inspecting the library with `readelf -d libbgfx-shared-libDebug.so` to see if X11 marked as a static dependency - it is not
- Checking from `/proc/1234/maps` that the shared X11 library is loaded - the same library is loaded in my C# test and in the included C++ example
- Running .NET Core without the debugger - no change
- Forcing preload of the *libbgfx-shared-libDebug.so* library with `LD_PRELOAD` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` - no change
- Commenting the offending line at *glcontext_glx.cpp:66* and rebuilding - the error changed from `undefined symbol: XLockDisplay` to `undefined symbol: glXQueryVersion`, which is called in the next line
- Adding `-lm -lpthread -lX11` flags to the compiler (as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313896#comment87646662_50313896) by [jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng)) - that error line is not printed anymore, but the program still crashes when `XLockDisplay` is called

#### Interesting things

Static dependencies of *libbgfx-shared-libDebug.so*:

```
user@ASUS-MINT ~/Documents/Projects/GameEngine/GameEngine/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0 $ readelf -d libbgfx-shared-libDebug.so 

Dynamic section at offset 0x1571d0 contains 28 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
 (snip)
```

Maps for *dotnet* while running my code:

```
user@ASUS-MINT ~ $ cat /proc/32502/maps
00400000-00418000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 185073                             /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet
(snip)
7fe844bed000-7fe844d42000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1616067                    /home/user/Documents/Projects/GameEngine/GameEngine/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/libbgfx-shared-libDebug.so
7fe844d42000-7fe844f42000 ---p 00155000 08:06 1616067                    /home/user/Documents/Projects/GameEngine/GameEngine/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/libbgfx-shared-libDebug.so
7fe844f42000-7fe844f45000 r--p 00155000 08:06 1616067                    /home/user/Documents/Projects/GameEngine/GameEngine/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/libbgfx-shared-libDebug.so
7fe844f45000-7fe844f4d000 rw-p 00158000 08:06 1616067                    /home/user/Documents/Projects/GameEngine/GameEngine/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/libbgfx-shared-libDebug.so
(snip)
7fe8455aa000-7fe8456df000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2370342                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7fe8456df000-7fe8458df000 ---p 00135000 08:06 2370342                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7fe8458df000-7fe8458e0000 r--p 00135000 08:06 2370342                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7fe8458e0000-7fe8458e4000 rw-p 00136000 08:06 2370342                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
(snip)
```

Maps for the included C++ example (no reference to *libbgfx-shared-libDebug.so*):

```
user@ASUS-MINT ~ $ cat /proc/351/maps
00400000-007fe000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1607279                            /home/user/bgfx/bgfx/.build/linux64_gcc/bin/examplesDebug
(snip)
7f6ad126c000-7f6ad13a1000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2370342                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7f6ad13a1000-7f6ad15a1000 ---p 00135000 08:06 2370342                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7f6ad15a1000-7f6ad15a2000 r--p 00135000 08:06 2370342                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7f6ad15a2000-7f6ad15a6000 rw-p 00136000 08:06 2370342                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
(snip)
```

Comment: You need to link with X11 libs. g++ -o testImage -O2 -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lm -lpthread -lX11  ./test.o  See : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2256551

Comment: I suspected that (since `readelf` does not list *libX11* in the dependencies), but I don't understand where to add the switch in the buildscript. Also I don't understand why the author of the bgfx library didn't do it already. Anyway, I will try to do as you say, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I found where to add `-lm -lpthread -lX11` switches and rebuilt. Now that error is not printed anymore, but the program still crashes on the same line.

Comment: I would recompile entire project by deleting the bin folder in the c# project.  Sometimes when a library is updated the compiler dependencies are not recognizing the library updates so files do not get compiled properly.

Comment: See following webpage : http://geekshells.org/cgi-bin/man2web?program=XLockDisplay&section=3

Comment: I am calling `XInitThreads` before interacting with X, as suggested from the man page you linked... but wait, maybe I'm missing something important: no library is involved with the C# build, I only link at runtime through PInvoke.

Comment: The entry point in the c++ code may change so c# needs to get the new entry point.  I'm not sure if the entry point is found during the c# compile or at runtime.  The c++ needs to be recompiled completely after the library option changes.

Comment: AFAIK PInvoke links at runtime, anyway I tried doing a full C++ and C# rebuild; unfortunately it did not solve the problem. Thanks a lot for the help you provided, I really appreciate it. I will continue investigating this on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel guilty answering my own question without a real solution, but here I go...

I kept investigating how to solve this problem with no avail. After two years of inactivity, I decided to try again.

Since 2018 I have formatted my computer and installed various operating system updates, probably even some X11 updates; I updated all project dependencies, including bgfx, to the latest version; and I upgraded from .NET Core App 2.0 to 3.0.

Maybe there was something wrong with the version of bgfx that I was using? Maybe there was a bug in the dynamic linking in that version of the .NET runtime? Maybe there was a problem with my version of Xlib.so?

I guess I will never really know, but now it works. Magic.